# ¿por que me cierra la aplicación al elegir la cámara para hacer una foto?

Tags: android-studio, permisos, android-imageview, android-manifest

Mi programa trata sobre un el registro de un usuario y la elección del usuario de su foto de perfil, si la quiere elegir de galería o tomar una foto.

Les agradecería la ayuda llevo tiempo buscando pero no encuentro nada.

```
private static String APP_DIRECTORY = "MyPictureApp/";
private static String MEDIA_DIRECTORY = APP_DIRECTORY + "PictureApp";

private final int MY_PERMISSIONS = 100;
private final int PHOTO_CODE = 100;
private final int SELECT_PICTURE = 200;

private ImageView mSetImage;
private Button mOptionButton;
private RelativeLayout mRelative;

private String mPath;

//imagenes
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_usuario);
    //imagen
    mSetImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.setimage);
    mOptionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonimage);
    mRelative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);

    if (myRequestStoragePermission()) {
        mOptionButton.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        mOptionButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
    mOptionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showOptions();
        }
    });
    //imagen

    nombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texnombre);
    nombreusuario = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texusuario);
    contraseña = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texcontraseña);
    apellido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texApe);
    sex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texgenero);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    String username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
    String password = intent.getStringExtra("password");
    String surname = intent.getStringExtra("surname");
    String gender = intent.getStringExtra("gender");


    nombre.setText(name);
    nombreusuario.setText(username);
    contraseña.setText(password);
    sex.setText(gender);
    apellido.setText(surname);

}

private boolean myRequestStoragePermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        return true;
    }
    if ((checkSelfPermission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
            (checkSelfPermission(CAMERA)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
        return true;
    }
    if ((shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))|| (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CAMERA))){
        Snackbar.make(mRelative, "los permisos son necesarios para el funcionamiento de la aplicacion",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }).show();
    }else {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS);
    }
    return false;
}

private void showOptions() {

    final CharSequence[] option = {"Tomar foto", "Elegir de galeria", "Cancelar"};
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Usuario.this);
    builder.setTitle("elige tu opcion");
    builder.setItems(option, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (option[which] == "Tomar foto") {

                openCamera();

            } else if (option[which] == "Elegir de galeria") {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "selecciona tu imagen"), SELECT_PICTURE);

            } else {

                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        }
    });

    builder.show();

}

private void openCamera() {

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), MEDIA_DIRECTORY);
    boolean isDirectoryCreated = file.exists();

    if (!isDirectoryCreated) {
        isDirectoryCreated = file.mkdirs();
    }
    if (isDirectoryCreated) {
        Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 100;
        String imageName = timestamp.toString() + ".jpg";

        mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + MEDIA_DIRECTORY
                + File.separator + imageName;
        File newFile = new File(mPath);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(newFile));
        startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("file_path", mPath);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mPath= savedInstanceState.getString("file_path");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode== RESULT_OK){
        switch (requestCode){
            case PHOTO_CODE:{

                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                        new String[]{mPath}, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned" + path + ":");
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "->Uri = " + uri);
                            }
                        });


                Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);
                mSetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                break;
            }
            case SELECT_PICTURE:{
                Uri path= data.getData();
                mSetImage.setImageURI(path);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode== MY_PERMISSIONS){
        if(grantResults.length==2 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(Usuario.this, "Permisos Aceptados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mOptionButton.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
            showExplanation();
        }
    }
}


private void showExplanation() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(Usuario.this);
    builder.setTitle("Permisos denegados");
    builder.setMessage("Para usar las funciones de esta aplicacion necesitas aceptar los permisos");
    builder.setPositiveButton("aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Intent intent= new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            Uri uri= Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
public void  grupo(View view){
    Intent intent=new Intent(Usuario.this, grupo.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

}
```

---

Aquí esta el log de la aplicación es al llamar la actividad de la cámara por lo que creo entender.

[image]

---

**Manifests**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<protected-broadcast android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Registro" />
    <activity android:name=".Usuario" />
    <activity android:name=".grupo"></activity>
</application>
```

```
05-11 19:21:59.699 3472-3472/com.example.marko.proyectop3 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-11 19:22:28.660 3472-3472/com.example.marko.proyectop3 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
    SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-11 19:22:31.068 3472-3472/com.example.marko.proyectop3 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
    SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-11 19:22:31.070 3472-3472/com.example.marko.proyectop3 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
    SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-11 19:22:39.144 3472-3472/com.example.marko.proyectop3 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
    SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-11 19:22:39.156 3472-3472/com.example.marko.proyectop3 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
    SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-11 19:22:39.171 3472-3472/com.example.marko.proyectop3 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
    SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-11 19:23:18.873 3472-3472/com.example.marko.proyectop3 E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
05-11 19:23:18.873 3472-3472/com.example.marko.proyectop3 E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
05-11 19:23:18.881 3472-3472/com.example.marko.proyectop3 E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/MyPictureApp/PictureApp/1526084598.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1816)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2353)
        at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:832)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9070)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9055)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1530)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4391)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4335)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
        at com.example.marko.proyectop3.Usuario.openCamera(Usuario.java:167)
        at com.example.marko.proyectop3.Usuario.access$100(Usuario.java:33)
        at com.example.marko.proyectop3.Usuario$3.onClick(Usuario.java:129)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1067)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:313)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1203)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3197)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4154)
        at android.widget.HwAbsListView.onTouchUp(HwAbsListView.java:518)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3898)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10013)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2665)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2344)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:447)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1871)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:939)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:409)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10233)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4865)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4726)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4311)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4277)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4404)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4285)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4461)
        at android.view.Vi
05-11 19:23:18.882 3472-3472/com.example.marko.proyectop3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.marko.proyectop3, PID: 3472
    android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/MyPictureApp/PictureApp/1526084598.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1816)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2353)
        at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:832)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9070)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9055)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1530)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4391)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4335)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
        at com.example.marko.proyectop3.Usuario.openCamera(Usuario.java:167)
        at com.example.marko.proyectop3.Usuario.access$100(Usuario.java:33)
        at com.example.marko.proyectop3.Usuario$3.onClick(Usuario.java:129)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1067)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:313)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1203)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3197)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4154)
        at android.widget.HwAbsListView.onTouchUp(HwAbsListView.java:518)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3898)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10013)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2665)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2344)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:447)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1871)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:939)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:409)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10233)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4865)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4726)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4311)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4277)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4404)
05-11 19:23:18.883 3472-3472/com.example.marko.proyectop3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4285)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4461)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4311)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4277)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4285)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6690)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6664)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6625)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6819)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:356)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Comment: Podrías publicar el log de la app? Ahí hay un mensaje Unhandler Exception... que te va a indicar el motivo del cierre de la app.

Comment: es que al cerrar se me queda abierto el activity anterior por lo cual no se en donde se encuentra el cierre de este.

Comment: Intenta ir a `Run/Debug Configuration` y cambia `MainActivity` por `App`. Si eso no funciona,edita tu pregunta y añade el Manifest

Comment: @Crazyytu Los mensajes de error en el LogCat se muestran con color rojo, lo que muestras no es de mucha ayuda, te recomiendo agregar el texto del error y no la imagen de toda la IDE, saludos.

Comment: todo lo que puse al ultimo es lo que esta en rojo en el logcat le puse lo que me dio error y fue todo eso, perdonen soy nuevo en esto

Comment: El problema es que la seguridad cambió con el target sdk >= 24 y hay una Uri expuesta. En cuanto saque algo de tiempo te formulo una respuesta que solucionará tu problema.